# Different options of sed - Get duplicate line or not

Tags: linux, shell, sed, replace, duplicates

I want to find a text in a file in linux and replace this text by another text. For example replace `B101011938` by `B101011939`

If I'm using Command1 (C1), there are duplicate lines in the output:

```
$ cat file
line1:B101011938
$ sed 's/B101011938/B101011939/p' file
line1:B101011939
line1:B101011939
```

If I'm using Command2 (C2), there are no duplicated lines:

```
$ cat file
line1:B101011938
$ sed 's/B101011938/B101011939/g' file
line1:B101011939
```

My question is: What is the difference between those commands?

Answer (score 0):

The substitute command in `sed` has the following signature:

```
s/REGEX/replacement/flags
```

Following [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html), the value of flags shall be zero or more of:

> **n** Substitute for the nth occurrence only of the BRE found within the pattern space.
>
> **g** Globally substitute for all non-overlapping instances of the BRE rather than just the first one. If both g and n are specified, the results are unspecified.
>
> **p** Write the pattern space to standard output if a replacement was made.
>
> **w**  wfile Write. Append the pattern space to wfile if a replacement was made. A conforming application shall precede the wfile argument with one or more blanks. If the w flag is not the last flag value given in a concatenation of multiple flag values, the results are undefined.

---

That means, when the `p` flag is in use `sed` will output the pattern space (the current line, modified by `s`). Since `sed` will already output the pattern space by default - unless the `-n` command line option is in use - this leads to having the modified line twice in the output.